Stop loss wont trigger in entry bar and results in margin call
I am using a stepped exit strategy that will exit at either the stop loss, breakeven, or 2 profit targets; this part of the strategy works well. The problem is that if the price goes under the stop loss level in the same bar where the entry occurred, it wont trigger the stop loss until the bar closes. Since the strategy is intented to be used with high leverage, this issue would result in a margin call which is completely unacceptable.
My understanding is that this delay happens because the code checks if the strategy is long and then generates the stop, which results in a one-bar delay and no protective stop on the entry bar. The solution would be generating the stop loss at the same time the entry order is placed using from_entry="Enter Long", which I tried and made no difference.
//Long Entry
if (GoLong)
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long)

// sl & tp in points
sl = input(1000)
tp1 = input(500)
tp2 = input(3500)
tp3 = input(5000)

curProfitInPts() =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        (high - strategy.position_avg_price) / syminfo.mintick
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        (strategy.position_avg_price - low) / syminfo.mintick
    else
        0

calcStopLossPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.position_avg_price - OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick
    else if strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.position_avg_price + OffsetPts * syminfo.mintick
    else
        0

calcProfitTrgtPrice(OffsetPts) =>
    calcStopLossPrice(-OffsetPts)

getCurrentStage() =>
    var stage = 0
    if strategy.position_size == 0
        stage := 0
        stage
    if stage == 0 and strategy.position_size != 0
        stage := 1
        stage
    else if stage == 1 and curProfitInPts() >= tp1
        stage := 2
        stage
    else if stage == 2 and curProfitInPts() >= tp2
        stage := 3
        stage
    stage

stopLevel = -1.
profitLevel = calcProfitTrgtPrice(tp3)

// based on current stage set up exit
// note: we use same exit ids ("x") consciously, for MODIFY the exit's parameters
curStage = getCurrentStage()
if curStage == 1
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(sl)
    strategy.exit('x', loss=sl, profit=tp3, comment='sl or tp3') 
else if curStage == 2
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(0)
    strategy.exit('x', stop=stopLevel, profit=tp3, comment='breakeven or tp3')
else if curStage == 3
    stopLevel := calcStopLossPrice(-tp1)
    strategy.exit('x', stop=stopLevel, profit=tp3, comment='tp1 or tp3')
else
    strategy.cancel('x')

